# I need help finding an element with a locator

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get the elements from this xpath here is the code, there is several of these elements I cut the code down to avoid a million lines on here.

html

```
<keyword-text class="_nghost-fyp-81"><div class="keyword-text _ngcontent- 
fyp-81" clickabletooltiptarget="" aria-label=""><span class="keyword 
_ngcontent-fyp-81" aria-hidden="false">new york new york las vegas</span> 
<!----></div><!----><!----></keyword-text>
```

xpath

```
keyword_text = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[starts-with(@class, 'keyword')]")
```

errors

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="941dc1eba2f3f61bb47aa2050889d299", element="0f74389d-13b7-42e8-ba81-429388d6647c")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="941dc1eba2f3f61bb47aa2050889d299", element="edc98646-f4e3-4ec9-8307-c12c110a219a")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="941dc1eba2f3f61bb47aa2050889d299", element="a6e12a98-22f4-4b1b-aad1-4831dcdb00a0")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="941dc1eba2f3f61bb47aa2050889d299", element="89f50425-8d53-4292-8e33-2a268f62c8b1")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="941dc1eba2f3f61bb47aa2050889d299", element="d7af6e64-6aa9-4fd0-9f9e-034f56d69c0d")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="941dc1eba2f3f61bb47aa2050889d299", element="1566c190-3809-4c40-b0c7-1051502bc658")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="941dc1eba2f3f61bb47aa2050889d299", element="f8304581-fba4-42c9-8332-8fbe5f05daf7")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="941dc1eba2f3f61bb47aa2050889d299", element="b6d79b66-874e-4233-9100-af4242a34c1b")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="941dc1eba2f3f61bb47aa2050889d299", element="a21f9c54-0dbf-4e4c-8055-f007c1b26c80")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="941dc1eba2f3f61bb47aa2050889d299", element="1e3dcbd6-a2de-4335-8688-f5dd5391d5dd")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="941dc1eba2f3f61bb47aa2050889d299", element="61bff097-3394-4b90-93e7-c5aeb199321b")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="941dc1eba2f3f61bb47aa2050889d299", element="ddc2fe2b-1d50-4e6c-909f-3f47c704a36d")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="941dc1eba2f3f61bb47aa2050889d299", element="0061e31c-3607-43c3-a984-c28130771119")>
```

Comment: show your code looks like you are printing something kind of object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following console messages...

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="941dc1eba2f3f61bb47aa2050889d299", element="0f74389d-13b7-42e8-ba81-429388d6647c")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="941dc1eba2f3f61bb47aa2050889d299", element="edc98646-f4e3-4ec9-8307-c12c110a219a")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="941dc1eba2f3f61bb47aa2050889d299", element="a6e12a98-22f4-4b1b-aad1-4831dcdb00a0")>
```

...are not any errors as such.

As you have used **`find_elements*`**, the resultant `keyword_text` was a list of objects of type *WebElements* and when you printed them, the objects were printed.

To print the texts e.g. **new york new york las vegas** from the several of these elements you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "keyword-text>div.keyword-text>span.keyword")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//keyword-text/div[contains(@class, 'keyword-text')]/span[contains(@class, 'keyword')]")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: `keyword_text = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[starts-with(@class, 'keyword')]")
  for keyw in keyword_text:
   print(keyw)
` this is how I printed it out

Comment: @user2217947 Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: oh yes that worked is this code from remote webdriver I will have to read more into that.

Comment: @user2217947 Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: now I feel silly, I was able to get the original code working by adding .text haha your code reminded me @user2217947